# How do you set the color of the bullet in an unordered list?

Tags: itext

I am using iTextSharp to create a bulleted list like so:

```
Dim ul As New iTextSharp.text.List(List.UNORDERED, 10)
ul.SetListSymbol(ChrW(&H2022))

Dim li As New iTextSharp.text.ListItem()
li.Add(New Chunk("...", myFont))
...

ul.Add(li)
```

The problem is that the bullet in the unordered list is always black regardless of the color of the list item (as defined by `myFont`). I'd like the list item color and the bullet color to match, but I don't see how to set the color of the bullet.

Thanks

Comment: What is ChrW? Does it return a `string` or a `Chunk` with font `myFont`?

Comment: @Bruno, `ChrW` is a built-in Visual Basic function that returns a specific unicode character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ListItem` is a subclass of `Paragraph` which is basically a smart collection of `Chunk`s. The constructor to `Paragraph` and thus `ListItem` sets the default for further chunks that get added. Since you aren't setting any defaults in your constructor the system is using its own defaults which are black.

So instead of using the default constructor for `ListItem` and adding content with `ListItem.Add()` try using the constructor that takes a `Chunk`.

```
Dim li = New ListItem(New Chunk("...", myFont))
```

Subsequent calls to `li.Add()` will use the defaults from this constructor. If you're really married to the `Add()` path you should even be able to use this constructor with just `String.Empty` and your font information.

An alternative path is to manually set the `ListSymbol` using your specified font. For some reason `SetListSymbol()` only takes a string but there's a write-only property that you can use that takes an actual `Chunk`:

```
ul.ListSymbol = New Chunk(ChrW(&H2022), myFont)
```

Comment: Thank you, Chris. I went with the `ul.ListSymbol = ...` approach and it works as advertised. Thanks again.